# forms in tables cell height too great

Tags: html, forms, html-table

The following html results in the table row containing the forms being too tall.  Why does this happen (I've only viewed it in Firefox) and what do I need to shrink it down to just the height of the form 'boxes'.

```
<html>
<head><title>Table Test</title></head>
<body>
<center>
<p>The bottom row of the table is too tall for the contents ...</p>
<table border="1">
<tr><th align="center">Field Name</center></td><th align="center">Field Value</center></td><tr>
<tr><td align="right">KEYCODE</td><td>NANTC06500402.00417</td></tr>
<tr><td align="right">PADVER</td><td>nantC0402.0 </td></tr>
<tr><td align="right">PARISH_CODE</td><td>NANT</td></tr>
<tr><td align="right">TAGGED</td><td>0</td></tr>
<tr><td align="right">DATED</td><td>8410420 </td></tr>
<tr><td align="right">FORENAME</td><td>WILLIAM </td></tr>
<tr><td align="right">SEX</td><td>M </td></tr>
<tr><td align="right">FATHER_FORENAME</td><td>JOHN </td></tr>
<tr><td align="right">MOTHER_FORENAME</td><td>ANNE </td></tr>
<tr><td align="right">SURNAME</td><td>PALIN </td></tr>
<tr><td align="right">OCCUPATION</td><td>OSTLER </td></tr>
<tr><td align="right">RESIDENCE</td><td>NANT </td></tr>
<tr><td align="right">ADDITIONAL_INFORMATION</td><td>HOSPITAL STREET</td></tr>
<tr><td align="left">
      <form method="post" action="...">
      <input type="submit" value="PREV">
      <input type="text" name="keycode" value="NANTC06500402.00416" size="30" readonly>
      </form>
    </td>
    <td align="right">
      <form method="post" action="...">
      <input type="text" name="keycode" value="NANTC06600401.10001" size="30" readonly>
      <input type="submit" value="NEXT">
      </form>
    </td></tr>
</table>
</center>
</body></html>
```

I've tried using a div to hold each form (not shown in the code above), but this did not work.  I also tried to middle the forms vertically within the cell - that did not work either.

Is the problem my html or the way browsers render cell contents ... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that follows avoids the extra space problem, which I guess is a browser rendering issue that I am unable to resolve and have no explanation for.
The solution is a design change that makes the clickable entity the value itself rather than the words "next" and "prev". Thus, the server sees "next"/"prev" and the correct value, which is then easily processed. 
With this change, the extra space vanishes in FF11, FF27, IE, and Safari.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head><title>Table Test 2</title></head>
<body>
<center>
<p>The bottom row of the table is the correct size ...</p>
<form method="post" action="....">
<table border="1">
<tr><th align="center">Field Name</th><th align="center">Field Value</th></tr>
<tr><td align="right">KEYCODE</td><td>NANTC06500402.00417</td></tr>
<tr><td align="right">PADVER</td><td>nantC0402.0 </td></tr>
<tr><td align="right">PARISH_CODE</td><td>NANT</td></tr>
<tr><td align="right">TAGGED</td><td>0</td></tr>
<tr><td align="right">DATED</td><td>8410420 </td></tr>
<tr><td align="right">FORENAME</td><td>WILLIAM </td></tr>
<tr><td align="right">SEX</td><td>M </td></tr>
<tr><td align="right">FATHER_FORENAME</td><td>JOHN </td></tr>
<tr><td align="right">MOTHER_FORENAME</td><td>ANNE </td></tr>
<tr><td align="right">SURNAME</td><td>PALIN </td></tr>
<tr><td align="right">OCCUPATION</td><td>OSTLER </td></tr>
<tr><td align="right">RESIDENCE</td><td>NANT </td></tr>
<tr><td align="right">ADDITIONAL_INFORMATION</td><td>HOSPITAL STREET</td></tr>
<tr><td align="left">
       PREV
       <input name="prev" type="submit" value="NANTC06500402.00416">
    </td>
    <td align="right">
       <input name="next" type="submit" value="NANTC06600401.10001">
       NEXT
    </td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</center>
</body></html>
```

I apologise that I am not an expert and unable to provide an explanation or true solution. However, if you want to avoid extra space problems such as this, my reading around seems to suggest that it is best to redesign the html to have a single form for the table and to adjust the look of the content and processing accordingly, and as illustrated above.

I trust this may help someone ...

Answer (score 0):

I checked the code and this is rendering fine with same height of all the rows.

Although I found two misplaced tags which you should remove.

1. `</center>` after Field Name in first row
2. `</center>` after Field Value in first row

Also, you can use `type='hidden'` for key values near next/previous buttons if it's not essential to display those.

Do you have any external style sheet which is setting form's height?

Comment: Thanks for looking at this.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this Boshi. There may well be "global" style sheets that I'm unaware of but would they not affect your sight of the table as much as mine (which has the extra space)? How do I, in this code, switch off their effect for this table?

Comment: The values in the next and previous boxes are required so type='hidden' would be inappropriate.

Comment: You can't be unaware of external stylesheet as you need to `link` them in <head> tag. Here I don't see any stylesheet linked. I asked for that to check whether it's the only code you are using or a part of that. You can use Firebug/Chrome dev tools to check what's wrong with the height in your browser.

Comment: This is all the code there is and in my browser (Firefox 11.0) it shows the extra space.  If your browser Boshi does not show it, I guess it must be a browser rendering issue rather than the html?

Comment: That could be the case. Here it shows up fine on firefox and chrome.

Comment: Which firefox version do you use? My Ipad Safari and Desktop IE and two other machines with IE have the extra space problem.  I have older Firefoxes than my 11.0 (which I guess will show the problem) and don't have Chrome ...

Comment: FF 27.0 and Chrome 32.0. Use firebug, it helps.

Comment: Just tried it on a Dell laptop FF 27.0.1 with Firebug and extra space shows. The Firebug indicates that the extra space is associated with the form, and not the <input ...> elements. However, what exactly the rendering is using to calculate width/height is not clear and I'm not sure I can determine that in Firebug?